# LDAP Group Mapping Openshift Origin

Tags: ldap, openshift-origin

I have a problem with the groupmapping in Openshift. Here is my ad-config.yaml:

```
kind: LDAPSyncConfig
apiVersion: v1
bindDN: "ldapuser"
bindPassword: "ldappwd"
insecure: true
url: "ldap://ldap.mycomp.local:389/ou=MyCompany,dc=mycomp,dc=local?sAMAccountName"
activeDirectory:
    usersQuery:
        baseDN: "OU=MyCompany,DC=mycomp,DC=local"
        scope: sub
        derefAliases: never
        filter: (objectclass=person)
        pageSize: 0
    userNameAttributes: [ sAMAccountName ]
    groupMembershipAttributes: [ memberOf ]
    groupsQuery:
        baseDN: OU=Sicherungsgruppen,OU=Gruppen,OOU=MyCompany,DC=mycomp,DC=local
        scope: sub
        derefAliases: always
        timeout: 0
        filter: (objectClass=group)
        pageSize: 0
    groupUIDAttribute: dn
    groupNameAttributes: [ cn ]
    groupUIDNameMapping:
        "CN=uxwsadmin,[...],OU=MyCompany,DC=mycomp,DC=local": admins
        "CN=JAVA-Entwickler,[...],OU=MyCompany,DC=mycomp,DC=localc": dev
```

Both groups are in a whitelist. I am syncing with `oc adm groups sync --whitelist=whitelist.txt --sync-config=adconfig.yaml --confirm`

When I check the result with `oc get groups`:

```
NAME                                                       USER
CN=JAVA-Entwickler,[...]OU=MyCompany,DC=mycomp,DC=localc   user1, user2, user3
CN=uxwsadmin,[...],OU=MyCompany,DC=mycomp,DC=local         user4, user5
```

Why fails the Groupmapping?

P.S. I tried oc version 7.0 and oc version 7.1.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have a same issue.